# How to Redirect to My App, After user reached the destination using Google Map Apps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-api

I am developing ionic application for android. From my application, I want to open google map app.

I have implemented the navigation using the given link below,

> https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator/

I have added the following code for this,

```
  launchnavigator.isAppAvailable(launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS, function(isAvailable){
       var app;
       if(isAvailable){
            app = launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS;
       }else{
            alert("Google Maps not available - falling back to user selection");
            app = launchnavigator.APP.USER_SELECT;
       }
         launchnavigator.navigate([50.279306, -5.163158], {
             start : "50.342847, -4.749904"
       });
  });
```

***I can able to navigate to google map. But, Once If I reached the destination, I am not able to redirect to my App.***

Anyone Can provide me the solution to achieve this !!!

Help will be Appreciated!!!